# Is it possible to schedule a task for removing a certain folder after a while with Node.js and Redis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, redis

I have a project based on `Node.js`, in which I need to implement automatic removal of the folder along with all its contents after 10 hours. I do not think that the `setTimeout` is suitable for this. A large number of temporary folders will be created in the application, which will have to be “self -destroyed” after a certain time till its creation. Storage in RAM is also not suitable, since the data can be too large. I would like the removal to happen, even if the server is not launched. However, the command to create this schedule should be performed within the server. Is it possible to implement this using `Redis` and it's npm client? Or what is more applied if `Redis` is not a suitable tool. Thanks for attention.

Comment: As far as I found out, Redis does not perform such tasks. I will look for the most optimal ways.